# Strange behaviour with costructors in Ruby C extension

Tags: c, ruby, constructor, ruby-c-extension

I have see strange behaviour with class costructors in Ruby C extension.
See an example: we have a class `Foo` that is a C extension and a class `Bar` that inherits from `Foo`:

*extconf.rb*

```
# extconf.rb
require 'mkmf'
create_makefile('foo/foo')
```

*foo.c*

```
// foo.c
#include "ruby.h"
#include <stdio.h>

VALUE
foo_new (VALUE class)
{
  printf ("foo_new\n");
  int *ptr;
  VALUE tdata = Data_Wrap_Struct (class, 0, 0, ptr);
  rb_obj_call_init (tdata, 0, 0);
  return tdata;
}

VALUE
foo_init (VALUE self)
{
  printf ("foo_init\n");
  return self;
}

VALUE
foo_plus_one (VALUE self, VALUE x)
{
  printf ("foo_plus_one\n");
  return INT2FIX (FIX2INT (x) + 1);
}

void
Init_foo ()
{
  VALUE foo = rb_define_class ("Foo", rb_cObject);
  rb_define_singleton_method (foo, "new", foo_new, 0);
  rb_define_method (foo, "initialize", foo_init, 0);
  rb_define_method (foo, "plus_one", foo_plus_one, 1);
}
```

*bar.rb*

```
# bar.rb
require './foo'

class Bar < Foo
end
```

Ok let's see strange stuffs...
In this situation all go ok:

```
x = Bar.new
```

we get the 2 prints: `foo_new` and `foo_init`.
Ok good, BUT if we change the class `Bar` in this way:

```
# bar.rb
require './foo'

class Bar < Foo
  def initialize(param = 1)
  end
end
```

we have the first strange stuff if we run

```
x = Bar.new
```

we get only 1 print: `foo_new`. And `foo_init` ??
Ok, we can bypass this problem adding an explicit call to the constructor of `Foo`:

```
# bar.rb
require './foo'

class Bar < Foo
  def initialize(param = 1)
    super()
  end
end
```

We get the 2 prints: `foo_new` and `foo_init` if we call `x = Bar.new`.

The second strange stuff is this:
if we call

```
x = Bar.new(2)
```

we get the error

```
in `new': wrong number of arguments(1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
```

But the constructor of `Bar` accept one parameter with default value.
Why this? Is this a Ruby bug?

(tested with ruby1.9.3-p0 [ x86_64 ])

Comment: `p Bar.new.class` prints `Foo`, right?

Comment: `Bar.new.class` prints `Bar`, `Foo.new.class` prints `Foo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined `::new` to take no arguments, so `wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)` is expected. Anyway, `::new` shouldn't be redefined. The right way to do it is defining the `::allocate` method (`::new` calls it internally).

This should work:

```
// foo.c
#include "ruby.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void foo_free (void *ptr) {
    free (ptr);
}

VALUE foo_alloc (VALUE class) {
    printf ("foo_alloc\n");
    int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    return Data_Wrap_Struct (class, 0, foo_free, ptr);
}

VALUE foo_init (VALUE self) {
    printf ("foo_init\n");
    return self;
}

void Init_foo (void) {
    VALUE cFoo = rb_define_class ("Foo", rb_cObject);
    rb_define_alloc_func (cFoo, foo_alloc);
    rb_define_method (cFoo, "initialize", foo_init, 0);
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks!!! I have follow this doc: http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ext_ruby.html (see the example)...